# Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query Warning when running query

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I am using .NetCore2.0 and EntityFrameworkCore.

When I execute the following:

```
Expression<Func<Foobar, bool>> predicate = 
    x =>
        query.Foos.Any(a => a.Contains(x.Foo)) &&
        query.Bars.Any(s => s.Contains(x.Bar));

 var results = GetAll().AsQueryable().Where(predicate);
```

I get the following warning messages in my console:

> warn: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query[200500]
>          The LINQ expression 'Any()' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.
>       warn: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query[200500]
>          The LINQ expression 'where [a].Contains([x].Foo)' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally
>       warn: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query[200500]
>          The LINQ expression 'where [a].Contains([x].Bar)' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally

The query itself does work and returns what I am looking for however I was wondering if there was a way to avoid these warnings or to suppress them

Comment: What is `query` (and `query.Foos`, `query.Bars`)?

Comment: @IvanStoev `query.Foos` and `query.Bars` are string arrays

Comment: Ok. Apparently this is one of the current EFC unsupported translations to SQL. The warning can be suppressed, but note that the filtering will happen in memory. The only way to avoid it is to replace `Any(...)` with manually built `Or` based expression, which I guess you are not willing to do.

Comment: @IvanStoev thanks for this info. Currently I am trying to make it extensible for further options that may come along. Essentially, I want it to only apply the `Contains()` when the array has something in it. Otherwise I just want it to return all but I am struggling with this and I thought that the warnings might have had something to do with it! Thanks.

Comment: You are hitting this https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/8019. The main issue is not translating is, while the predicate is expression tree, the `Array.Any` is func and not expression so EF cannot inspect it and translate it.

Answer (score 1):

On our system, enabling this error was a deliberate decision on our part and was done by configuring the dbContextOptionsBuilder.  I'll paste how we've turned it on so you can find where this must be in your system:

```
            services.AddDbContext<FooContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(BarConnectionString,
                    sqlServerOptions => sqlServerOptions.CommandTimeout(300)).UseLazyLoadingProxies()
                                  .ConfigureWarnings(warnings =>
                                  warnings.Throw(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Diagnostics.RelationalEventId.QueryClientEvaluationWarning))
                    );
```

Note that this is actually something useful as it's flagging that your query won't be entirely ran on the server so could be a performance problem.